# Return array value as NSString

Tags: objective-c, string, arrays

How can you return an array value (witch is a number) as a string?

Current code:

```
return [numbers objectAtIndex:row];
```

Have also tried:

```
return @"%@", [numbers objectAtIndex:row];
```

With no luck..

Thanks :)
PS: Yes, I am stupid. (:

Comment: You again?! :) Definitely keep asking questions here, but If you're new to Objective-C, I cannot recommend highly enough this book: http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Programming-Mac-OS-3rd/dp/0321503619. Spend a couple hours and plow through the tutorials. It got me up to speed a few years ago on Obj-C/Cocoa in a small number of hours and was hugely beneficial.

Comment: I will get a book, the only thing is that I live in Norway, and we don't have many book stores with programming books ;)

Comment: If you can find an old copy on eBay.no or wherever, it's really worth every penny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return [[numbers objectAtIndex:row] description];
```

---

In C / ObjC / C++ / Javascript / D / many other C-based languages, the comma operator does not create an array / tuple.

```
(a,b,c,d,e)
```

is similar to

```
e
```

(while evaluating `a` and `b` and `c` and `d` as a side-effect).

Comment: +1 for talking about the unloved comma operator. But beware newbies that we don't write `(a, b, c, d, e)` almost ever in C languages.

Comment: Btw, object**s**AtIndex is not valid :)

Comment: You really don't want to use `-description`.  Use `-stringValue` instead.

Comment: Because -description is a method that is intended to describe an object in a debugging or logging role.   -stringValue is intended for purposes of display and the like.